# Is 35mm 1.8 lens suitable for Product, interior photography?

Tags: lens, nikon, equipment-recommendation, 35mm, product-photography

I'm still a beginner, is 35mm lens is suitable for product photography, mostly e-commerce products and hotel room pictures.

Comment: It would help if you specify the camera type e.g. cropped sensor, full frame.

Comment: My first thought is that these 2 types of photography would ideally need different lens types - possibly a macro (and indeed, even _tilt_ lens) for product photography, and probably something wider for interiors (and here, a _shift_ lens would probably be ideal).

Comment: Also, please state what lens(es) you have already.

Comment: What is the size of the products and how much room do you have to work with?

Comment: A "Product photography" could be a thimble or a motorcycle. A hotel room could be a tiny one or a suite.

Answer (score 6):

Not really.

- For hotel rooms you will need a rather wide angle-lens (35mm max, ideally 20mm or less for a full-frame sensor, 20mm max, ideally 15mm or less for crop sensor) because you rarely have enough space (unless you are shooting luxury suites in palaces, and even then...)
- For product photography (objects 10-50cm in size) you need a somewhat long lens (around 50mm for crop sensor, 80mm for FF) so that you are far enough to not introduce perspective distortion (the "big nose" syndrome when shooting people) even if this less critical.